# Convert PNG Sequence as Moving Object

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

Can you convert PNG Sequence around 200 Frame as plane on Blender ? The cases is, i wanna cast the shadow of of my png sequence using one light to curtain 3d model , the image i attach is the closest reference i can get. Thanks before 
 [image: Reference]

Comment: You could use a lamp as a projector of your images as an image-sequence, e.g. as illustrated by @rjg [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dINvL.jpg)

Comment: Thankyou for your responses, glad i found the solution now, i found it hard before how to cast a "black light" to a surface, i just need to project the images but, before that i have to change the color of the png image sequence to white, then in blender, i set the strength of the emission to negative value, @RobinBetts Thanks Alot